# how can I get the member mentioned and displayed in the embed

Tags: java, discord-jda

```
if(msg.equalsIgnoreCase("hi")){
            Member member = event.getMessage().getMentions().getMembers().get(0);
            EmbedBuilder embedBuilder = new EmbedBuilder();
            embedBuilder.setColor(Color.cyan);
            embedBuilder.setDescription("Hello, " + member.getUser().getName() + "!");
            embedBuilder.build();
            event.getChannel().sendMessageEmbeds(embedBuilder.build()).queue();
```

message: hi @mentioned
expected answer: hello @mention or name

Answer (score 0):

Get the user's ID and put it in between of `<@` and `>`. Example: <@355314189117554689>.

```java
if (msg.equalsIgnoreCase("hi")) {
  Member member = event.getMessage()
    .getMentions()
    .getMembers()
    .get(0);

  EmbedBuilder embedBuilder = new EmbedBuilder();
  embedBuilder.setColor(Color.cyan);
  // simply put the users snowflake ID between <@ and >
  embedBuilder.setDescription("Hello, <@" + member.getUser().getId() + ">!");
  embedBuilder.build();
  event.getChannel().sendMessageEmbeds(embedBuilder.build()).queue();
}
```

Comment: Just use `member.getAsMention()`, regardless discord won't handle this as expected since mentions are not supported in embeds.

Answer (score 0):

To get a mention of a member you can use `member.getAsMention()`, in your case if you would like to actually mention someone, you would need to do it in the actual message (not the embed itself) as **embeds do not support mentions** and so it will be formatted in a weird way.

Alternatively you can just get the users name using `member.getEffectiveName()` and prepend it with '@' so it would look like a mention, but won't actually mention anyone